# ArcGIS Pro tool equivalent to QGIS "Create layer from extent"

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers, extents

Is there a tool or combination of tools in ArcGIS Pro that can create a feature class that corresponds to an existing feature class extent similar to the QGIS tool *Create Layer from Extent*?

I want to create a simple rectangular polygon dataset based on the extent of another layer.  This will be used to do some batch processing. The function *Minimum Bounding Geometry* in ArcGIS isn't appropriate as it creates polygons for the bounding area of features rather than a rectangular polygon like QGIS creates.  I have looked through the list of tools and can't identify an appropriate tool. I have searched the toolbox using keywords such as *extract, extent, make, create, bounding*, but haven't found the right tool.
Here is how it is done in QGIS:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not only is there one, but there are probably many such tools and combinations of tools. This is the problem with asking a Boolean question when what you want is a short answer response. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: For the sake of those who are more familiar with ArcGIS than with QGIS, you should explain what it is you actually want to achieve... in detail.  Perhaps a screenshot of the QGIS tool and an explanation of each of the parameters would be useful.  Yes, I could probably look it up, but you need to make it easy for people to understand your question, not make them do research to understand your question.

Comment: Correct tool, but first dissolve to single multi part feature.

Comment: Great - thanks.  that didn't occur to me!

Comment: Possibly [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) with "Group Option" parameter set to "All".

Comment: Great - thank you - another useful option